# Springboot - MongoDb queries taking too long

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using springboot with mongodb in our project.

I have two collections. For simplicity lets call them foo and bar.
Foo has bar as Dbref inside its documents.

I have a query on Foo where I am querying it on bar.$id

```
{ "bar.$id" :  ObjectId("61405393108f544d3b2082ed")}
```

I have indexed Foo collection on bar.$id

THere are 14K documents in Foo collection right now and 5 bar documents.

However, when I am calling this query from mongo repository, it is taking more than 1 min to execute.

When I analyzed the issue using explain(), I saw that on mongoDb side, the query is executed in under 100 ms. Result of explain:

```
{ queryPlanner: 
   { plannerVersion: 1,
     namespace: 'development.foo',
     indexFilterSet: false,
     parsedQuery: { 'bar.$id': { '$eq': ObjectId("61405393108f544d3b2082ed") } },
     winningPlan: 
      { stage: 'FETCH',
        inputStage: 
         { stage: 'IXSCAN',
           keyPattern: { 'bar.$id': 1 },
           indexName: 'index1',
           isMultiKey: false,
           multiKeyPaths: { 'bar.$id': [] },
           isUnique: false,
           isSparse: false,
           isPartial: false,
           indexVersion: 2,
           direction: 'forward',
           indexBounds: { 'bar.$id': [ '[ObjectId(\'61405393108f544d3b2082ed\'), ObjectId(\'61405393108f544d3b2082ed\')]' ] } } },
     rejectedPlans: [] },
  executionStats: 
   { executionSuccess: true,
     nReturned: 7011,
     executionTimeMillis: 6,
     totalKeysExamined: 7011,
     totalDocsExamined: 7011,
     executionStages: 
      { stage: 'FETCH',
        nReturned: 7011,
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: 1,
        works: 7012,
        advanced: 7011,
        needTime: 0,
        needYield: 0,
        saveState: 7,
        restoreState: 7,
        isEOF: 1,
        docsExamined: 7011,
        alreadyHasObj: 0,
        inputStage: 
         { stage: 'IXSCAN',
           nReturned: 7011,
           executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
           works: 7012,
           advanced: 7011,
           needTime: 0,
           needYield: 0,
           saveState: 7,
           restoreState: 7,
           isEOF: 1,
           keyPattern: { 'bar.$id': 1 },
           indexName: 'index1',
           isMultiKey: false,
           multiKeyPaths: { 'b.$arid': [] },
           isUnique: false,
           isSparse: false,
           isPartial: false,
           indexVersion: 2,
           direction: 'forward',
           indexBounds: { 'bar.$id': [ '[ObjectId(\'61405393108f544d3b2082ed\'), ObjectId(\'61405393108f544d3b2082ed\')]' ] },
           keysExamined: 7011,
           seeks: 1,
           dupsTested: 0,
           dupsDropped: 0 } } },
  serverInfo: 
   { host: 'XXXX.0.mongodb.net',
     port: 27017,
     version: '4.4.9',
     gitVersion: 'XXXX' },
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': 
   { clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1632909970, i: 19 }),
     signature: 
      { hash: Binary(Buffer.from("XXXX", "hex"), 0),
        keyId: XXXX } },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1632909970, i: 19 }) }
```

Springboot code:

```
@Query(value="{ 'bar.$id' : ObjectId(?0) }")
List<Foo> findByBarId(String barId);
```

Questions:

1. Why is spring boot taking too long to process query results?
2. Any solution to optimize this?

Comment: "nReturned: 7011" - the number of documents matching the request condition. I'm not sure, but if mongo was used as a remote service, it could take 1 minute to transfer so many heavy documents over the network. Just write a simple Python script without any frameworks and execute locally to check network transfer times. Maybe it's not about spring boot.

Comment: When i am firing the same query from compass, then it is taking 1-2 seconds only. So, I don't think its network issue

Comment: Your query plan says: `executionTimeMillis: 6,` (and thats not long).

Comment: Yeah, But when i am calling it from springboot, it takes more than 1 min.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who are facing a similar issue,

I resolved the issue, by adding turning on the lazy evaluation in Dbrefs.

```
@DBRef(lazy = true)
private bar bar;
```

I was retrieving the list of 14K documents each with one Dbref object and without mentioning `lazy=true`, all those objects were getting resolving eagerly which was causing the delay.